# What Mac app shows this 'Control Center'-like interface on the side of the desktop?

Tags: macos, ui

I saw these pictures on a forum and I was wondering what app is it?
I am referring to the the nice little UI on the left middle of the screen..

[image]
[image]

So I see they both have a 'beats' icon in their menu, so is it a beats headphone plugin or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [**Control Center**](http://www.cindori.org/software/controlcenter/) by Cindori

[image]